# MySQL UPDATE based on complex select

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT assets.serial, employees.uid from assets
inner join emp_as on assets.serial = emp_as.serial
inner join employees on concat(emp_as.first_name,emp_as.last_name) = concat(employees.first_name,employees.last_name)
```

That returns two columns, an `asset serial` (unique) and an `employee ID`. I want to update the `assets.employee_id` field to be the `select.employee_id where the asset.serial = select.serial` (select being pseudocode for the result from that query).

Comment: What do you mean by `select.employee_id`??

Comment: I mean the employee_id that is in the result of the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
UPDATE assets set assets.employee_id = employees.uid
inner join emp_as on assets.serial = emp_as.serial
inner join employees on concat(emp_as.first_name,emp_as.last_name) = concat(employees.first_name,employees.last_name)
```

Comment: Can not run this. There's a syntax error in it near "from assets".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database, I can't be 100% sure this is what you want, but I believe this should work. Mysql is very kind about allowing updates on joins so you don't need to worry about creating a temp table or a subquery.

```
update assets
join emp_as on assets.serial = emp_as.serial
join employees on concat(emp_as.first_name,emp_as.last_name) = concat(employees.first_name,employees.last_name)
set assets.employee_id = employees.uid
```

Comment: Forget that, it is because the select statement isn't even returning all of the rows